# Как авторизоваться на сайте с помощью java?

Tags: java

Как авторизоваться на сайте с помощью java?
Такое возможно на Delfi. А как в Java это сделать?

Мой код

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair;
```

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    POSTRequset();
}

public static void POSTRequset() throws IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://hashcode.ru/account/signin/");
    NameValuePair data[] = {
            new NameValuePair("csrfmiddlewaretoken", "e8aa8db221730e2718102d4cc967dd1f"),
            new NameValuePair("csrfmiddlewaretoken", "e8aa8db221730e2718102d4cc967dd1f"),
            new NameValuePair("username", "ЛОГИН"),
            new NameValuePair("password", "ПАРОЛЬ"),
            new NameValuePair("blogin", "Войти"),
            new NameValuePair("validate_email", "yes")
    };
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(data.toString(), "UTF-8"));
    String request = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
    if (request.contains("ИСКОМОЕ СЛОВО КОТОРОЕ ЕСТЬ на АВТОРИЗОВАННОЙ СТРАНИЦЕ и НЕТ в ТЕКУЩЕЙ")) {
        System.out.println("Авторизация прошла успешно!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ошибка!");
    }

    //System.out.println(request);
}
```

}

Вот такую ошибку получаю

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: FORBIDDEN
at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:67)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:52)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:218)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:136)
at Main.POSTRequset(Main.java:29)
at Main.main(Main.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: На общий вопрос можно дать только общий ответ - в Java это тоже возможно.

Comment: @xTIGRx, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Я погуглил и нашел 2-3 способа, особенно через HttpClient понравилось. Даже с помощью программы смотреть, что передает в POST запросе, и в итоге у меня получается, что код работает, но после авторизации он не загружает ту страницу, которая будет после авторизации, а грузится текущая страница. В итоге авторизация не проходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если через http пакеты хотите - [сюда](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/) за гайдом по отправке запроса.
Если через пакеты вам не нравится - попробуйте [Selenium](http://selenium2.ru/).